# Spotfire: Select data from column based on criteria

Tags: calculated-columns, spotfire

I have a data table in Spotfire which contains two columns I'm interested in: `Time` (31/01/2015 for example), and `Value` (integer).

I want the most recent date (e.g. December 2015) to be set as the current time. Then I want to select `Value` based on previous 1 month, 3 months, 6 months etc. So if I want all the values for past 6 months it should `Sum(Values)` for Dec.2015, November.2015, October.2015, September.2015, August.2015 and return that.

So far I've only been able to accomplish this by manually performing the task in Excel before I insert it into Spotfire so is there any way to create a calculated column for each of the periods I want? (Past month, 3 months etc.)

Comment: what exactly do you want to do? Add columns "previous 1 month" ... for the table with the same data in all rows, or get a visualization where you use these results?

Comment: I'd prefer to just get a visualisation - it doesn't have to populate new columns with Previous 1 Month, or Previous Year, etc. but if creating a calculated column is easier in order to put the answer in a visualisation like a graph or a table then either approach will suffice. 

The point is I do not want to manually perform the calculation in excel - I want the process to be automated so when I update the underlying table I don't have to repeat the process.

Answer (score 2):

There's likely a number of ways to solve this, but I'm going to give one suggestion and we'll see how it fits your specific case.

You can add a calculated column for each timespan you are interested in, defined like this:

```
Sum(if (DateAdd('month', 3, [Time]) >= Max([Time]), [Value], null))
```

This example would get you a column with all the values that have occured in the past 3 months, replace the number 3 in there to modify to the timespans you are interested in. A full sum of the calculated column would get you the total for that timespan.

Might be nicer to use a boolean column instead of duplicating the value column. Then your calculated columns would be defined as:

```
DateAdd('month', 3, [Time]) >= Max([Time])
```

When calculating totals you would then use an if statement using the calculated column, like this:

```
Sum(if([3Months],[Value],null))
```

where [3Months] is a boolean column.